# How POSIX Message Queue names used in makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a homework related to Operating Systems course. In this homework , two programs will be implemented: a client program called "get" and a server program called "iserv". The server will be a multi-process program. POSIX message queues will be used for inter-process communication. Server will be started as follows:
iserv  
Here ,  is the name of a message queue to be created by the server. is the name of a text file containing integer numbers.

My iserv.c program: ( not completed )

```
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>
#include <msg.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
pid_t apid1;
FILE *fp;
mqd_t mq;
const char *msgqueue = "/serverqueue";
int oflag = (O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
mode_t mode = (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
struct mq_attr *attr = NULL;

if(argc != 1)
{
    printf("wrong number of arguments");
    exit(1);
}
//create message queue
mq = mq_open(msgqueue ,oflag , mode , attr);
if(mq==-1)
{
    perror("can not open msg queue\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("mq opened , mq id = %d\n" , (int) mq);

//create child process
apid1 = fork();
if(apid1 < 0)
{
    perror("main():");
    exit(1);
}
if(apid1 == 0)
{
    printf("this is the first child, pid = %d\n", (int) getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
}
}
```

As the code suggests , message queue is created  with the name "serverqueue". Then , I have created my makefile as:

```
iserv:iserv.c
     gcc -o iserv serverqueue infile.txt -lrt
clean:
     rm -r *.o iserv
```

When I run this makefile with the make command , I get serverqueue: No such file or directory error. 
Where and how the server will be started with the line iserv   ? Where is the wrong?

Please help me , thanks!

Comment: Sorry , some words are missing , because I am a new user:)

Comment: I am rewriting these missing parts. Server will be started as follows: iserv <servq><inputfile> . Here , <servq> is the name of a message queue to be created by the server. ( I have created the name as server queue). However , I do not know where and how to put the message queue name in the makefile. Please help me..

Comment: what is the purpose of infile.txt in your gcc command?

Comment: Client will ask the server to retrieve and sent all integers in a certain range. Thus , infile.txt is the name of a text file that will contain a large number of positive integers(one integer per line).

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to pass infile.txt to the program during runtime?

Comment: In homework , it is wanted that server will be started as follows: iserv <servq> <inputfile>. servq is the name of a message queueto be created by the server and it is created as server queue in the code if I am true besides that inputfile is the name of a text file that will contain a large number of positive integers. This form is a requirement ; ı cannot throw away the name of the file. Thus , How can I start the server? If it is not in makefile , where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile makes no sense to me. 
-o specifies the name of the compiled output file.
If your source file is called iserv.c and you want your executable to be named serverqueue, compile

```
gcc -o serverqueue iserv.c -lrt
```

In your makefile you forgot the .c extension of the source file.

I don't understand the reason why you included infile.txt.

EDIT according to your comment:

> In homework , it is wanted that server will be started as follows: iserv  . servq is the name of a message queueto be created by the server and it is created as server queue in the code if I am true besides that inputfile is the name of a text file that will contain a large number of positive integers.

No, the statement `iserv <servq> <inputfile>` has nothing to do with the compilation. This is how the program should be used once the program is compiled. The name of the program is iserv, thus you have to compile your code like this

```
gcc -o iserv iserv.c -lrt
```

To start your program type

```
./iserv <servq> <inputfile>
```

where `<servq>` is your serverqueue and `<inputfile>` would be infile.txt.

Comment: In homework , it is wanted that server will be started as follows: iserv <servq> <inputfile>. servq is the name of a message queueto be created by the server and it is created as server queue in the code if I am true besides that inputfile is the name of a text file that will contain a large number of positive integers. This form is a requirement ; ı cannot throw away the name of the file. Thus , How can I start the server? If it is not in makefile , where is it?

Comment: Thank you so much:))) I am now able to start the server , but I am getting the error cannot open msg queue. I will now try to fix it !

Comment: Yes I have made it! I was trying to find the answer for hours , thank you so much again:))

Comment: @Begumm I mean clicking "accept as answer", so I also have a benefit for my invested time.

Comment: Ok , because I am new in this site, I could not understand what you mean. I have clicked.